# change month name to month number for the specific lines in sed awk or batch

Tags: batch-file, awk, sed

I have a file that contains the time of observations (time and date) with measurements.

**Input File:**

```
TimeStamp=Wednesday,February 21,2018 4:33:10 PM   
1,16.00,17.11,703.41,257.462,12.3,13.8   
2,17.11,18.30,753.61,308.084,13.8,15.3    
3,18.30,19.58,733.57,335.605,15.3,18.0   
TimeStamp=Wednesday,February 21,2018 4:35:54 PM  
1,16.00,17.11,638.19,233.251,12.3,13.5  
2,17.11,18.30,606.43,247.558,13.5,15.5  
3,18.30,19.58,708.14,323.502,15.5,18.2  
TimeStamp=Wednesday,February 21,2018 4:38:37 PM  
1,16.00,17.11,543.10,201.339,12.5,13.5  
2,17.11,18.30,542.06,224.449,13.5,15.3  
3,18.30,19.58,693.38,321.293,15.3,17.8
```

I want to convert the month name to month number for the specific lines, which contains the "TimeStamps=". Additionally, I also want to change the time from 12-hour format to 24-hour format.

**Output File:**

```
TimeStamp=Wednesday,02 21,2018 16:33:10  
1,16.00,17.11,703.41,257.462,12.3,13.8   
2,17.11,18.30,753.61,308.084,13.8,15.3    
3,18.30,19.58,733.57,335.605,15.3,18.0   
TimeStamp=Wednesday,02 21,2018 16:35:54  
1,16.00,17.11,638.19,233.251,12.3,13.5  
2,17.11,18.30,606.43,247.558,13.5,15.5  
3,18.30,19.58,708.14,323.502,15.5,18.2  
TimeStamp=Wednesday,02 21,2018 16:38:37  
1,16.00,17.11,543.10,201.339,12.5,13.5  
2,17.11,18.30,542.06,224.449,13.5,15.3  
3,18.30,19.58,693.38,321.293,15.3,17.8
```

Please help in this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What did you try yourself?

Comment: Yes I tried and I succeed to change only month name to month number, but the script became long and it's time-consuming. I have the multiple numbers of files to process. So I am looking for help.

Comment: Thank you npocmaka for editing a query

Comment: What have you tried, and how has what you've tried failed? Ideally, you should provide a [MCVE] of what you've tried, and include specific information on how it failed, with error messages and/or erroneous output. [SO] is not a code-writing service; the best questions are those which provide useful information so that those who answer can guide you to devising your own correct answer. See [Ask] a Good Question.

Answer (score 1):

Following sed script, may be a start, could be improved or fixed depending on input:

```
/^TimeStamp=/ {
 s/January/01/
 s/February/02/
 s/March/03/
 s/April/04/
 s/May/05/
 s/June/06/
 s/July/07/
 s/August/08/
 s/September/09/
 s/October/10/
 s/November/11/
 s/December/12/
 / PM *$/ {
  s/ PM *$//
  s/ 1:/ 13:/
  s/ 2:/ 14:/
  s/ 3:/ 15:/
  s/ 4:/ 16:/
  s/ 5:/ 17:/
  s/ 6:/ 18:/
  s/ 7:/ 19:/
  s/ 8:/ 20:/
  s/ 9:/ 21:/
  s/ 10:/ 22:/
  s/ 11:/ 23:/
 }
 / AM *$/ {
  s/ AM *$//
  s/ 12:/ 0:/
 }
}
```

The sed command

```
sed -f script_name < input_file > output_file
```

Answer (score 0):

using **awk**

```
$ awk -F "[, ]" ' /Time/{"date --date=\""$2" "$3" "$4"\" +%m" | getline m; "date --date=\""$5" "$6"\" +%T" | getline t; printf("%s,%02d %d,%d %s\n",$1,m,$3,$4,t); next}1' file
TimeStamp=Wednesday,02 21,2018 16:33:10
1,16.00,17.11,703.41,257.462,12.3,13.8
2,17.11,18.30,753.61,308.084,13.8,15.3
3,18.30,19.58,733.57,335.605,15.3,18.0
TimeStamp=Wednesday,02 21,2018 16:35:54
1,16.00,17.11,638.19,233.251,12.3,13.5
2,17.11,18.30,606.43,247.558,13.5,15.5
3,18.30,19.58,708.14,323.502,15.5,18.2
TimeStamp=Wednesday,02 21,2018 16:38:37
1,16.00,17.11,543.10,201.339,12.5,13.5
2,17.11,18.30,542.06,224.449,13.5,15.3
3,18.30,19.58,693.38,321.293,15.3,17.8
```

We are invoking `date` withing `awk`

`"date --date=\""$2" "$3" "$4"\" +%m" | getline m;`  : Passing required fields in date command and month integer result would get store in `m`

`"date --date=\""$5" "$6"\" +%T" | getline t;` : Similary `t` would have the time in 24hrs format

Comment: Thank you @batMan but I am having an error while using your syntax

Comment: - awk: cmd. line:1: /Time/{date  
-  awk: cmd. line:1: ^ unexpected newline or end of string

Comment: Sorry I am unable to write properly

Comment: Can you paste the exact command you used ? Also let me know the output of `awk --version`

Comment: I just pasted your answer as it is and I am using GNU awk 3.1.6

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set /A i=100, AM=0, PM=12
for %%a in (January February March April May June July August September October November December) do (
   set /A i+=1
   set "month[%%a]=!i:~1!"
)

(for /F "delims=" %%l in (input.txt) do (
   set "line=%%l"
   if "!line:~0,4!" equ "Time" (
      for /F "tokens=1-8 delims=,: " %%a in ("%%l") do (
         set /A hour=%%e+%%h
         set "line=%%a,!month[%%b]! %%c,%%d !hour!:%%f:%%g"
      )
   )
   echo !line!
)) > output.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Extended **`awk`** solution:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ 
         split("Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec", month);
         for (i in month) months[month[i]] = sprintf("%02d", i);
         FS = OFS = "," 
     }
     /TimeStamp/{ 
         sub(/^[^[:space:]]+/, months[substr($2, 1, 3)], $2);
         split($3, t, " ");
         h=sprintf("%02d", substr(t[2], 1, length(t[2])==8? 2 : 1) + (t[3]=="PM"? 12 : 0));
         if (h == 24) h="00";
         sub(/^[0-9]+/, h, t[2]); 
         $3 = t[1]" "t[2] 
     }1' file
```

The output:

```
TimeStamp=Wednesday,02 21,2018 16:33:10
1,16.00,17.11,703.41,257.462,12.3,13.8   
2,17.11,18.30,753.61,308.084,13.8,15.3    
3,18.30,19.58,733.57,335.605,15.3,18.0   
TimeStamp=Wednesday,02 21,2018 16:35:54
1,16.00,17.11,638.19,233.251,12.3,13.5  
2,17.11,18.30,606.43,247.558,13.5,15.5  
3,18.30,19.58,708.14,323.502,15.5,18.2  
TimeStamp=Wednesday,02 21,2018 16:38:37
1,16.00,17.11,543.10,201.339,12.5,13.5  
2,17.11,18.30,542.06,224.449,13.5,15.3  
3,18.30,19.58,693.38,321.293,15.3,17.8
```

Answer (score 0):

`awk` to the rescue! (using system date)

```
$ awk 'BEGIN         {FS=OFS=","}
       /^TimeStamp=/ {gsub(/ +$/,""); 
                      cmd="date -d \"" $2 " " $3 "\" +\"%m %d,%Y %T\""; 
                      cmd | getline $2; NF--}1' file

TimeStamp=Wednesday,02 21,2018 16:33:10
1,16.00,17.11,703.41,257.462,12.3,13.8
2,17.11,18.30,753.61,308.084,13.8,15.3
3,18.30,19.58,733.57,335.605,15.3,18.0
TimeStamp=Wednesday,02 21,2018 16:35:54
1,16.00,17.11,638.19,233.251,12.3,13.5
2,17.11,18.30,606.43,247.558,13.5,15.5
3,18.30,19.58,708.14,323.502,15.5,18.2
TimeStamp=Wednesday,02 21,2018 16:38:37
1,16.00,17.11,543.10,201.339,12.5,13.5
2,17.11,18.30,542.06,224.449,13.5,15.3
3,18.30,19.58,693.38,321.293,15.3,17.8
```